# How to make this matrix efficiently?

Tags: linear-algebra, blas

Originally posted on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157483/back-prop-question-can-this-gradient-be-decomposed), I'll pair the post down to something a bit more general.

Suppose I have vectors $\{\mathbf{\delta}, \mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_J\}$, where $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^{J}$ and $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{I}$. Furthermore, let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{I\times J}$ be such that
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\begin{pmatrix} 
\delta_1 \mathbf{x}_1 \\
\delta_2 \mathbf{x}_2 \\
\vdots \\
\delta_J \mathbf{x}_J
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there any sequence of BLAS-optimized operations that can make $\mathbf{A}$ from my set of vectors?

To be concrete, I understand that if I have the matrix
$$
\mathbf{B} =
\begin{pmatrix} 
 \mathbf{x}_1 \\
 \mathbf{x}_2 \\
\vdots \\
 \mathbf{x}_J
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then
$$
\text{diag}(\delta) \,  \mathbf{B} :=
\begin{pmatrix}
\delta_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \delta_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \delta_j
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf{B}
= \mathbf{A} 
$$
But it's not clear to me if making $\text{diag}(\delta)$ is an efficient operation, or even if the multiplication between $\text{diag}(\delta)$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is efficient.

*Edit:* I noticed that a similar, fortran, specific question was [asked and answered](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10667/what-is-the-best-way-to-multiply-a-diagonal-matrix-in-fortran). However that question addresses efficient ways to multiply diagonal matrices (in fortran, no less). Whereas, my question references the use of diagonal matrices as *one* way in which the solution can be approached. My thoughts are that this question is a bit more general than the aforementioned one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to multiply a diagonal matrix (in fortran)](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10667/what-is-the-best-way-to-multiply-a-diagonal-matrix-in-fortran)

Comment: If you're using a C-type language that uses row-major storage order I doubt you'll do better than `for (j=0; j<J; j++) {for (i=0; i<I; I++) { A[j][i] = delta[j] * B[j][i]; }};`. Storage order and cache efficiency is going to be the determining factor for speed.

Comment: This was basically my original line of thought. But, computational mathematics isn't really my field, and I figured there might be a more clever way that doing the row scaling myself...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni see edit.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I have vectors $\{\mathbf{\delta}, \mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_J\}$, where $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^{J}$ and $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{I}$. Furthermore, let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{I\times J}$ be such that
>   $$
> \mathbf{A} =
> \begin{pmatrix} 
> \delta_1 \mathbf{x}_1 \\
> \delta_2 \mathbf{x}_2 \\
> \vdots \\
> \delta_J \mathbf{x}_J
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

There's some confusion about notation here. As written, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{IJ}$; that is, is has one column and $IJ$ rows, instead of $I$ rows and $J$ columns.

> Is there any sequence of BLAS-optimized operations that can make $\mathbf{A}$ from my set of vectors?

What I think you're proposing essentially reduces to

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{x}_{1} & \ldots & \mathbf{x}_{J}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\delta_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \delta_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \delta_j
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}

followed by reshaping the result. I would not do that.

Instead, `dscal` each of the $\mathbf{x}_{i}$ by their respective $\delta_{i}$ in-place. As DougLipinski points out, this is basically just a `for` loop (or `do` loop in Fortran). A tuned BLAS implementation might do some loop unrolling.

> To be concrete, I understand that if I have the matrix
>   $$
> \mathbf{B} =
> \begin{pmatrix} 
>  \mathbf{x}_1 \\
>  \mathbf{x}_2 \\
> \vdots \\
>  \mathbf{x}_J
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   then
>   $$
> \text{diag}(\delta) \,  \mathbf{B} :=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \delta_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
> 0 & \delta_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> 0 & 0 & \cdots & \delta_j
> \end{pmatrix}
> \mathbf{B}
> = \mathbf{A} 
> $$
>   But it's not clear to me if making $\text{diag}(\delta)$ is an efficient operation, or even if the multiplication between $\text{diag}(\delta)$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is efficient.

The memory movement isn't worth it; also, the multiplication you've proposed isn't conformal, so it would not work. Likely, you intended to do what I show above.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't explicit enough about the specification of $\mathbf{A}$. As I've said, $\mathbf{A}$ is an I x J matrix. The i-th row of $\mathbf{A}$ is the J-dimensional vector, $\mathbf{x}_j$, scaled by the i-th component of the I-dimensional vector $\delta$. That is, $\mathbf{A}_{i,j}$ is, in pseudo-code, delta[i] * \mathbf{x}_{i}[j]... Does that make more sense?

Comment: @StevieP: Then the vectors in $\mathbf{A}$ should be transposed. The usual convention in mathematics is that $n$-vectors are $n \times 1$ matrices. In any case, yes, you could premultiply by a diagonal matrix, but it would probably be better for you to use BLAS level 1 primitives or a loop.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Ah, yes, right.